# Magento 2 - Buy minimal 2 products

Tags: magento2, product

We are using Magento 2.1

we have a cheap baby product in 10 different colors.
And sometimes people order just one of it.
With the shipping costs included this is not profitable.

Now we would like that they can't order a single one of this specific product anymore. A minimum of 2 need to be ordered.
But it can be 1 yellow and 1 blue ... or just 2 blue ....

What is the best way to set this up?
I can't figure it out what the best option is ....